# Tools is involved in synchronizing LDAP with User profile in SP 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Which tools is involved in synchronizing LDAP with User profile?

Plz reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest here, using the same keywords in your description above, in a search engine like Google or Bing will get you to the same thing I'm listing below and then some.  That being said since you are already here, the answer is the User Profile Service (UPS).

Excerpt from the Technet Article that came up in Search (there are other very good blog posts on this too):

**For Novell eDirectory, Sun Java System Directory Server, or IBM Tivoli Directory Server (ITDS), follow these steps:**

In the Directory Service Server Name box, type the name of the directory service server.

In the Authentication Provider Type box, select the type of authentication provider.

In the Authentication Provider Instance box, select the authentication provider.

The Authentication Provider Instance box lists only the authentication providers that are currently used by a web application.

In the Account name box, type the synchronization account in LDAP format, for example, uid=username,ou=ouname,dc=yourcompany,dc=Com.

In the Password box, type the password for the synchronization account.

In the Confirm Password box, type the password for the synchronization account again.

In the Port box, enter the connection port.

Verify that the Use SSL-secured connection check box is not selected.

SSL connections are not supported for these directory services.

In the Username attribute box, type the name of the attribute in the directory service that serves as the unique identifier of each profile.

In the Containers section, click Populate Containers, and then select the containers from the directory service that you want to synchronize.

Click OK.